# VPN and Firefox proxy

Tags: vpn

What happens if I use VPN and then configure my firefox browser to use SOCKS proxy? Am I then behind both or just proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox tries to connect to the SOCKS proxy server normally, but your operating system is routing all the traffic through the VPN server. So what happens simply is:

> Browser -> **VPN Server -> SOCKS Server ->** Destination server

**So, yes. You're behind both of them.**

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are behind both. When you are connected to a VPN all N/W connections to internet from all your applications is going through VPN. Again Firefox is an application and You are making a proxy connection to your proxy server.The server sees the VPN IP as your source IP.So You are behind both.